# Sqlite error loading sql file

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am getting the error

```
 Error: near line 15: near "s": syntax error
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have read through the DELETE documentation in sqlite but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong

```
DELETE s.*, c.*
FROM student s, cameras c, bookstore b
WHERE c.name = b.kname
AND b.mno = s.no
AND s.type = 'jumbo';
```

I am tried removing the .* also but seems to be getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try just `DELETE FROM student ...`.

Comment: I don't think SQLite supports joins in `DELETE` statements. You might need to reformulate the query to use a subquery instead to find the keys of the rows to delete. [See the documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html).

Comment: I tried removing s.*, c.* and still gives the same syntax error.

Comment: Please explain with normal words what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Again, please give *all* relevant code, ie your table & constraint definitions.

Answer (score 1):

1) `DELETE` deletes *rows* from a table.  It doesn't make sense to specify columns in the delete statement (and you aren't allowed to do so.  There should not be anything between `delete` and `from`).

2) `DELETE` operates on a single table, and you aren't allowed to join.  If you want to delete from two tables, you will need a delete statement for each, and you will have to use a subquery rather than a join if you need to reference another table.